# How to retrieve sharepoint list items attachments URL along with all other fields using REST API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs

PFB the code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {

            $scope.result=data.d.results;

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }

});
```

I am able to retrieve the list data with above code, now I need to retrieve attachments along with the list data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use OData syntax in the REST API to expand the attachments and return the ServerRelativeUrl:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/items?$select=AttachmentFiles,Title,AttachmentFiles/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

Check [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help (the whole script):

[https://afrait.com/blog/get-attachment-url-from-list-item-en](https://afrait.com/blog/get-attachment-url-from-list-item-en/)

Attachment is an Object. So get the whole object like this:

> var attachmentUrl = item.AttachmentFiles.results[0]

And then you could do this to get the file name:

> alert(attachmentUrl.FileName);

or save it to a variable of your choice.

Comment: But how do I iterate the attachments in ng-repeat ? When i perform item.AttachmentFiles.results[0].FileName , it is picking up only the first attachment

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the attachment files using the below code

```
 var requestUri = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('<List_Name>')/items?$select=Title,ID,Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles";
 var attachmentUrl;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: requestUri,
                        type: "GET",
                        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                        success: function (data) {

                            $.each(data.d.results, function (obj, itm){
                               attachmentUrl = item.AttachmentFiles.results;                            

                            })
                        },
                        error: function () {

                        }                     
                    });
```

To perform ng-repeat you can do,

```
<h1 ng-repeat="x in attachmentUrl ">{{x.FileName}} {{x.ServerRelativeUrl}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am showing you a POC of this, hope it works for you:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id='mydiv'>
  <table id='mytable'>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Attachment</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var listurl="/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('test1')/items?select=AttachmentFiles,Title,AttachmentFiles/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=AttachmentFiles";
getItems(listurl);
});
function getItems(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            for(i=0; i < data.d.results.length; i++){    //will get the list of items one by one till its length
                $("#mytable").append("<tr id='datatr" + i +"'>");    //'datatr'+i will create new rows for each item, you can work your way round
                $("#datatr" + i +"").append("<td>" + data.d.results[i].ID +"</td>");
                $("#datatr" + i +"").append("<td>" + data.d.results[i].Title +"</td>");
            if(data.d.results[i].AttachmentFiles.results.length > 0)
                $("#datatr" + i +"").append("<td><a href='" +_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + data.d.results[i].AttachmentFiles.results[0].ServerRelativeUrl +"'>" + data.d.results[i].AttachmentFiles.results[0].FileName + "</a></td>");    //if attachment is there it will print its hyperlink
            else $("#datatr" + i +"").append("<td>No attachment</td>");
            $("#mytable").append("</tr>");
                }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Here `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + data.d.results[i].AttachmentFiles.results[0].ServerRelativeUrl` will give you the complete url of the attachment file and `data.d.results[i].AttachmentFiles.results[0].FileName` will give you the file name.

Comment: @Dheeraj please mark correct if it works for you. Thanks 