# Attachment URL to column

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, flow, attachments, power-automate

Query is regarding SharePoint list.

Is there anyway I can get the attachment URL and add that to a new column using flow?[image: First image top of flow]

[[image: second image][1]]
[image: last image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Use **Get attachments** action to get the list item attachments.
2. You can get the attachment URL using **AbsoluteUri** dynamic property from above step.
3. Use **Update item** action to update the SharePoint list item.

Check below references to know more about how to get list item attachments:

1. [SharePoint list attachment link via flow](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/SharePoint-list-attachment-link-via-flow/td-p/203817)
2. [Get SharePoint attachment URIs as text string](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Get-SharePoint-attachment-URIs-as-text-string/td-p/398140)

Comment: Above is recommended way. Another workaround is to use REST API to get attachments URL like this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228414/how-to-retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-attachments-url-along-with-all-other-field

Comment: Ganesh, I do have this error message:
Are you able to direct me?
Flow save failed with code 'InvalidTemplate' and message 'The template validation failed: 'The inputs of template action 'Update_item' at line '1 and column '2146' is invalid. Action 'Apply_to_each' must be a parent 'foreach' scope of action 'Update_item' to be referenced by 'repeatItems' or 'items' functions.'.'.

Comment: I have also added images

Answer (score 0):

I created a [flow](https://isvdevchat.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/EYoBiqCJ1Y9MjkE5vlfnz0QBQ3MEuDZqLux983tcYYkZ8g?e=HEyoZ9) and repeated the steps on my SPO site, here it works fine.

[image]

From the error msg, it seems that 'Update_item' action references a field that comes from 'repeatItems' in 'Apply_to_each'. thus can you have a check the fields in 'Update_item'?

BR